# Create xslt template that creates childs based on condition, but with a new ascending Indexnumber (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt, jdf

I need to make a XSLT for changing a JDF file. In this file are 4 runlist items of which 2 have a "EndOfDocument" attribute.

```
      <RunList ID="RunList_1" NPage="1" PartIDKeys="Run" Status="Available" Class="Parameter">
         <RunList Run="Asset0" DescriptiveName="000202KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="1.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset1" DescriptiveName="000203KR" EndOfDocument="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="2.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset2" DescriptiveName="00020a3KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="3.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset3" DescriptiveName="0asas00203KR" EndOfDocument="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="4.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
      </RunList>
```

Based on this runlist I'm creating "GatheringParams" but the BundleItemIndex I create keeps stating 2 and 4 instead of 1 and 2 as I want it

```
   <ResourcePool>
      <GatheringParams PartIDKeys="BundleItemIndex" ID="GP001" Status="Available">
         <GatheringParams BundleItemIndex="2" />
         <GatheringParams BundleItemIndex="4" />
      </GatheringParams>
      <Media Class="Consumable" DescriptiveName="Media001" ID="Media001" Status="Available" />
      <Media Cla2ss="Consumable" DescriptiveName="Media00" ID="Media002" Status="Available" />
      <DigitalPrintingParams Class="Parameter" ID="DPP001" Collate="Sheet" OutputBin="AutoSelect" PartIDKeys="DocIndex DocRunIndex" Status="Available">
         <DigitalPrintingParams DocIndex="0 ~ -1">
            <DigitalPrintingParams DocRunIndex="0 ~ 1">
               <MediaRef rRef="Media001" />
            </DigitalPrintingParams>
            <DigitalPrintingParams DocRunIndex="2 ~ -1">
               <MediaRef rRef="Media002" />
            </DigitalPrintingParams>
            <Disjointing OffsetDirection="None" />
            <MediaRef rRef="Media001" />
         </DigitalPrintingParams>
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
      <RunList ID="RunList_1" NPage="1" PartIDKeys="Run" Status="Available" Class="Parameter">
         <!-- sourceItemID = 000202KR -->
         <RunList Run="Asset0" DescriptiveName="000202KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="http://10.31.31.68/1.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <!-- sourceItemID = 000203KR -->
         <RunList Run="Asset1" DescriptiveName="000203KR" EndOfDocument="true" EndOfBundleItem="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="http://10.31.31.68/2.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <!-- sourceItemID = 000203KR -->
         <RunList Run="Asset2" DescriptiveName="00020a3KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="http://10.31.31.68/3.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset3" DescriptiveName="0asas00203KR" EndOfDocument="true" EndOfBundleItem="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="http://10.31.31.68/4.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
      </RunList>
      <Component ID="Component" ComponentType="FinalProduct" Status="Unavailable" Class="Quantity" />
   </ResourcePool>
```

```
   <ResourcePool>
      <GatheringParams PartIDKeys="BundleItemIndex" ID="GP001" Status="Available">
         <GatheringParams BundleItemIndex="2" />
         <GatheringParams BundleItemIndex="4" />
      </GatheringParams>
      <Media Class="Consumable" DescriptiveName="MagnoPlusGloss_250_320x460" ID="Media001" Status="Available" />
      <Media Class="Consumable" DescriptiveName="MagnoPlusGloss_115_320x460" ID="Media002" Status="Available" />
      <DigitalPrintingParams Class="Parameter" ID="DPP001" Collate="Sheet" OutputBin="AutoSelect" PartIDKeys="DocIndex DocRunIndex" Status="Available">
         <DigitalPrintingParams DocIndex="0 ~ -1">
            <DigitalPrintingParams DocRunIndex="0 ~ 1">
               <MediaRef rRef="Media001" />
            </DigitalPrintingParams>
            <DigitalPrintingParams DocRunIndex="2 ~ -1">
               <MediaRef rRef="Media002" />
            </DigitalPrintingParams>
            <Disjointing OffsetDirection="None" />
            <MediaRef rRef="Media001" />
         </DigitalPrintingParams>
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
      <RunList ID="RunList_1" NPage="1" PartIDKeys="Run" Status="Available" Class="Parameter">
         <RunList Run="Asset0" DescriptiveName="000202KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="1.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset1" DescriptiveName="000203KR" EndOfDocument="true" EndOfBundleItem="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="2.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset2" DescriptiveName="00020a3KR">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="3.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
         <RunList Run="Asset3" DescriptiveName="0asas00203KR" EndOfDocument="true" EndOfBundleItem="true">
            <LayoutElement>
               <FileSpec MimeType="application/pdf" URL="4.pdf" />
            </LayoutElement>
         </RunList>
      </RunList>
      <Component ID="Component" ComponentType="FinalProduct" Status="Unavailable" Class="Quantity" />
   </ResourcePool>
```

As the GatheringParams are set up in a select within the ResourcePool I tried to setup a second loop :

JDF/ResourcePool/GatheringParams/

to update the GatheringParams-chlild from here end adding the BundleItemIndex but that didnt work

Comment: I tried:  <xsl:template match="JDF:JDF/JDF:ResourcePool/JDF:GatheringParams/JDF:GatheringParams">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="BundleItemIndex">
    <xsl:number format="1" />
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 
in a second xslt, then it worksm but why notin one XSLT? And how to do in in One?

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead. Also please reduce the code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem and add the expected result - see: [mcve].